# How to pass variables from electron to the angular behind

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, electron

I want to make a website and desktop app with one single codebase. But because there are some minor differences, I need to know in the angular app whether the app got called from the web or from electron.

In the main.js I have already tried:

Putting a URL parameter in the `loadFile` function like this:

```
win.loadFile('dist/project/index.html?electron=true')
```

but then it doesn't find the file anymore.

I have tried to make a second '`index.html`':

```
win.loadFile('dist/project/electron.html')
```

but that html does not get compiled with angular.

Comment: To pass data you can use an ipc channel, but I think that you need only check if is in web or Electron environment, see the answer below

More info about ipc channel: https://dev.to/michaeljota/integrating-an-angular-cli-application-with-electron---the-ipc-4m18

Answer (score 1):

In your angular side you can check the process global constant, the package @types/node must be instaled

```
cont inElectron = process.versions.hasOwnProperty('electron');
console.log(inElectron);
// true if the app is running in electron, otherwise false
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lrgkgv